# Rails on Docker - Ignoring GEM because extensions are not built

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I've been going crazy with this error for the past two days. I am attempting to Dockerize a Rails 6 application

As per [this](https://ledermann.dev/blog/2018/04/19/dockerize-rails-the-lean-way/) I am doing my Dockerfile in two stages to minimize the size of the resulting image. Everything seems to work as expected: I `bundle install` and `yarn install` in the build stage and then copy it over to the final stage. However, when attempting to actually start the server (via `bundle exec rails s`) I get the following error:

```
Could not find nokogiri-1.10.9 in any of the sources
```

When running bash in the relevant container, we can inspect `bundle` for the gems that it knows about. However, `bundle list` fails with the above error. Just running `bundle` gives us a clue:

```sh
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.13 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.13
Ignoring bootsnap-1.4.6 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.4.6
Ignoring ffi-1.12.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.12.2
Ignoring msgpack-1.3.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine msgpack --version 1.3.3
Ignoring nio4r-2.5.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nio4r --version 2.5.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.10.9 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.10.9
Ignoring pg-1.2.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine pg --version 1.2.3
Ignoring puma-4.3.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine puma --version 4.3.3
Ignoring sassc-2.2.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine sassc --version 2.2.1
Ignoring websocket-driver-0.7.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine websocket-driver --version 0.7.1
```

In the build stage, `bundle install` was run with the `deployment` option set to true, which means that all of the gems were installed in the local `vendor/bundle`. Indeed, we can see that `nokogiri` and the rest of the missing gems, along with their built extensions, are actually in that folder:

```sh
/usr/src/app> ls -R vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux-musl/2.6.0/
# ...
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux-musl/2.6.0/nokogiri-1.10.9:
gem.build_complete  gem_make.out        mkmf.log            nokogiri

vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux-musl/2.6.0/nokogiri-1.10.9/nokogiri:
nokogiri.so
# ...
```

Of course, the problem can be fixed in the final image by installing the relevant build dependencies and then running `bundle install`. Before doing it we can see where `nokogiri`'s compiled libraries are, which `bundle` can't find:

```sh
/usr/src/app > find / -name nokogiri.so
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux-musl/2.6.0/nokogiri-1.10.9/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9/ext/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
```

After running `bundle install`, `bundle` is able to find `nokogiri` just fine. But where is it?

```sh
/usr/src/app > find / -name nokogiri.so
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux-musl/2.6.0/nokogiri-1.10.9/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/nokogiri-1.10.9/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9/ext/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
```

Aha! So, in the build stage, we need to build for the `x86_64-linux` platform instead of the `x86_64-linux-musl` platform, whatever that is. The question: how do we accomplish this?

```
bundle config set specific_platform x86_64-linux
```

I've already tried setting the above during the build, and it does not work. Any ideas?

This post is lengthy enough: so here is a link to my [Dockerfile](https://github.com/app-academy-exercises-jb/YASC/blob/dockerized/Dockerfile). If you'd like to try it yourself, make sure to use `docker-compose up` in order to launch the necessary psql server.